# When piping from ffmpeg to ffplay, the ffplay video window does not appear. Is there some way to observe ffplay output in real time?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

When I run a single ffplay play command like the following:

```
ffplay "/home/pete/Desktop/2FPS-copy.webm"
```

I get a terminal output and video output window like this:
[image]

However, when I am piping from ffmpeg (which I need to do), the window does not appear. I am running this:

```
ffmpeg -re -i /home/pete/Desktop/2FPS.webm -c copy -f webm - | ffplay -f webm -
```

Is there a way to get this window to appear when piping ffmpeg to ffplay?